# Difference between a skiplist and an Indexable skiplist

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, search-algorithms, lists

Can someone please help me understand the main differences between a simple skiplist and an indexable skiplist? How does an indexable skiplist work in comparison to a normal skiplist (maybe a little example?), I can only find so little about it online.
Thanks.

Comment: (Please add *what contents* found *here* you think should have helped, and *how* it didn't.)

Answer (score 2):

An [Indexable Skiplist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list#Indexable_skiplist) is a skiplist with the added property that it can quickly lookup the $m$th entry (in order) in a skiplist in $O(\log n)$ time in a skiplist of $n$ entries.  In other words, it takes a skiplist that is not an indexable skiplist $O(n)$ time, on average, to find the $m$th element in order in a skiplist, while an ordered skiplist can do this in logarithmic time.

It does this by keeping track of the width of the links in the skiplist.